# Encrypting content with assymetric key pairs as a form of signing

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

The use-case is as follows:

There is a signer that have a claim or document D who wants any client to be able to verify that D has not been tampered with.

I suppose one way to do this is to use assymetric encryption where: E = encrypt(D, K_priv), using his private key K_priv.

Then any client who get access to the public key K_pub and E can decrypt it to be sure that noone have tampered with the claim. The signer wants to avoid to encrypt D every time a new client connects so he desires to have a pre-encrypted version, E, and a public key K_pub that anyone can use instead.

The private and public keys here are only used for signing claims and not to encrypt communication.

My question is: Is this a valid solution for this use case? If not, what is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question on multiple sites!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd question; are you unaware that asymmetric digital signatures are already a thing (and are in fact much more commonly used than asymmetric encryption)?

Mathematically, **in the specific case of RSA**, it works a lot like you describe. In practice you hash D first using a cryptographic hash function, and then "encrypt" the hash digest with the private key (scare quotes there because asymmetric encryption and signing have different important considerations around padding and threat models and so on, even though *mathematically* it's the same operation just with the other key part). The signature consists of the "encrypted" hash digest, the hashing algorithm used, and usually some indicator of who the signer was (so you don't have to try every public key you have).

For other common asymmetric digital signature algorithms such as DSA, ECDSA, and Ed25519, it's pretty different. In fact, none of those algorithms actually support encryption at all! That's fine though, because signatures don't require *confidentiality* - the property that encryption gives you - and aside from integer DSA they're all much faster and use much smaller keys to achieve equivalent security levels compared to RSA. (Note: you probably shouldn't use [integer] DSA; it isn't very strong with the 1024 bit keys that are standard, and there are some attacks on it unless you regenerate certain properties every time. ECDSA, or Ed25519 which is an improvement on a subset of ECDSA with fewer parameters to get wrong, is generally a better choice.)

In all cases, the signing party generates a key pair, distributes the public key to whoever wants it, signs any message(s) they want with the private key, and distributes those message(s)+signature bundles to whomever they choose to receive them. This is a fundamental part of most modern secure communication protocols, from TLS to PGP to Signal.

Comment: Thanks for the references and clarification! I'm a bit new to the subject and just try to understand how it is done properly.